# split lines and print it to new line for certain character

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to split lines and print it to next line when pattern match.

Like I have:

```
ABC123xxx:: 2345 ABC345yyy:: 5678 ABC986zzz:: 7955
```

And I want it to print to new line when `ABC` pattern will come:

```
ABC123xxx:: 2345
ABC345yyy:: 5678
ABC986zzz:: 7955
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -E -e 's/ (ABC)/\n\1/g'
```

The `sed` command replaces any instance of `ABC` with a newline followed by ABC.  It uses the `()` to capture part of the match (`ABC` without the leading space) and `\1` to include it in the replacement.

e.g.

```
$ echo 'ABC123xxx:: 2345 ABC345yyy:: 5678 ABC986zzz:: 7955'| 
    sed -E -e 's/ (ABC)/\n\1/g'
ABC123xxx:: 2345
ABC345yyy:: 5678
ABC986zzz:: 7955
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -e 's/ ABC/\
ABC/g' <file
ABC123xxx:: 2345
ABC345yyy:: 5678
ABC986zzz:: 7955
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this awk.

```
echo "ABC123xxx:: 2345 ABC345yyy:: 5678 ABC986zzz:: 7955" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(match($i,"ABC")>0) line=line "\n"$i;else line=line $i; sub("^\n","",line); print line}'
```

Creates a line with all fields, adding in front of the fields that begin with "ABC" a line break. Finally it eliminates the first line break and prints